# Taxonomic ranks of spaces

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, noneuclidean-geometry

Where might I find a good overview of different categories of space? I am most interested in the idea of a taxonomy as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) (multiple levels of classification listed with differentiating features germane to each level listed, as well).

I've done some search engine exploring but the returned results don't seem to be as comprehensive or explicit as I would prefer.

Comment: We do have Inner Product Space$\subset$ Normed space$\subset$ Metric Space $\subset$ Topological Space

Comment: But, what you have asked is too general, to be given a decent answer

Comment: As daruma was getting at, there are so many uses/contexts of "space" in so many different subsubfields of math that this is not a reasonable question. Something that attempted to be a "good overview" of all of them would be too large and complex and have totally separate ideas that it wouldn't be useful. That wikipedia page is probably close to the best you'd get...